# Is a circle a manifold?

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds, circles

I am very much a beginner when it comes to manifolds. I understand that the torus in $\mathbb{R}^3$ is given by
$$
T^2 = \left\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3\, : \, \left(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + R^2 - r^2\right)^2 - 4R^2(x^2+ 
 y^2) = 0\right\}
$$
And its dimension is $2$ because we have $1$ constraint so $3 - 1 = 2$.

Then my question is this: what's the dimension of the circle manifold? It comes out as zero to me.

$$
C = \left\{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,:\, y = y_0 + \sqrt{r^2 - (x-x_0)^2}\text{ and } y = y_0 - \sqrt{r^2 - (x-x_0)^2} \right\}
$$
So now we have $2$ constraints and so $2-2 = 0$.

Comment: By the way, if you're going to use explicit graph charts, you'll need four of them (note that you have problems when $y=y_0$ above).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dimension of $C$ is one. If you see it as$$\left\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2\,\middle|\,(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2\right\},$$then there is only one constraint, and $2-1=1$.

Besides, your description of $C$ should be$$C = \left\{(x, y)\in\mathbb{R}^2\,\middle|\, y = y_0 + \sqrt{r^2 - (x-x_0)^2}\color{red}{\text{ or }} y = y_0 - \sqrt{r^2 - (x-x_0)^2} \right\}.$$

Comment: OR!!! Oh my god I can't believe I spent so much wondering why the squared formula worked but not the other version...